# Couchbase Lite: Cannot access internal constructor "Document" here

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to use [Couchbase Lite 2.0](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/guides/couchbase-lite/index.html) (Developer preview #21) in a Xamarin.Forms application. My code sharing project is a .NET Standard 2.0 application.

So I'm following the docs about this developer preview. My problem is when I try to create a [new Document](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/2.0/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html) object. At this point the IDE is saying that I `Cannot access the internal constructor "Document" here`.

```
var db = new Database("test");
var document = new Document(); // error raised in this line
```

But this is the way that the docs indicates to create a new Document object. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm - the docs for Document don't show any public constructors: http://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.0/couchbase-lite-net/db021/html/T_Couchbase_Lite_Document.htm

Comment: Looks like the user guide is basically out of date. Maybe use a MutableDocument?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes! seems like you are right! :) Now I'm getting a "DLL not found error", but this is another question... Please answer my question with the content of your comments and I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth an answer to just point out that the docs are wrong - I don't know whether using a MutableDocument is the *right* solution. Hopefully someone who's actually used Couchbase will respond.

Comment: @JonSkeet as you can see in this [official sample app](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-travel-sample/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22new+MutableDocument%22&type=) from Couchbase Lite Github Repo the MutableDocument class is used to create and persist data. So I think this is a good indication that this is the right way to use Couchbase lite version 2.0.

Comment: I'm sufficiently non-confident in it that I'd still rather not add an answer. You could add an answer yourself though, if you wish.

Comment: @JonSkeet right, I will wait. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I appreciate you popping your head in here.  Your solution is in fact correct.  I'm not sure why the docs indicate Document unless there is some cache issue.  For me all the examples show MutableDocument use.  Also in the future, the best way to get the immediate up to date API usage is by either looking at the unit tests in the repo or by looking at the API-Walkthrough project inside of the docs folder in the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an question on [Couchbase Forum](https://forums.couchbase.com/):

> The API changed a few DBs back to switch to an immutable first
>   paradigm. So now things have a “Mutable” counterpart that you can
>   mutate. In this case the class you want is MutableDocument. For what
>   it’s worth this is all mentioned in the release notes. If the release
>   notes are hard to find, though, then that is another story.

That is:

When using Couchbase Lite 2.0 you should instantiate a `MutableDocument` instead of `Document`.